# SharePoint 2019 Distributed Cache Service

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, server-farm, distributedcache

Just wondering if someone can offer me some advice, I have recently configured a SharePoint 2019 farm with server mini roles, this consists of:

- 1 Application Server
- 1 Search Server
- 2 x Web Front End & Distributed Cache

I have fully patched the farm and configured everything as expected, however I have recently noticed that the Distributed Cache Service is only showing as running on 1 server. If I go to the other server that is not displaying the distributed cache server as stopped I can see that the AppFabric Caching service is running as expected.

If can also run a PowerShell script that display the service status of the cache, this shows two servers both with the service status **up**.

Can someone please provide me with some advice, should I be seeing the distributed cache service displaying started on both servers that have the combined roles? If so what am I doing wrong? I have tried running:

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

However this just displays in central administration that the service is not compliant on the server.

Appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have just  resolved this, I first removed the distributed cache using:

```
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

Then I added it again using:

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

It is now showing at started on services on server.